# Elementary Set-Theory problem concerning two logicians: did I get it right?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was looking at this optional question from my university tutorial regarding set basics:

"Mr. P and Mr. Q are two logicians. They are very honest people who never lie. One day, they are sitting together, being interviewed for a detective job. The interviewer, X, took out a box with 16 poker cards and showed them the cards:

$♥: A, 4, Q$

$♠: 2,3,4,7,8,J$

$♣: 4,5,6,Q,K$

$♦: A,5$

X then hides these cards under his desk and draws one card out of these 16 cards. Secretly, he tells Mr. P the denomination of this card, and tells Mr. Q the suit of this card. They are not allowed to share what they know with each other.

X then asks 'Can you infer, from what you know, both the denomination and the suit of the card I drew?'

Mr. P and Mr. Q look at each other and start this conversation:

P: 'I don’t know what this card is.'

Q: 'I knew you didn’t know what this card is.'

P: 'In that case, I know what it is.'

Q: 'Oh, now I also know what it is.'

Now, X turns to you and asks “What is the suit and the denomination of this card?”

Write down your answer and reasoning."

**The answer I got was $4$ of $♥$**

*My reasoning:*

Take the element, which is a card denomination, found in the intersection of the most sets (in this context, suits) possible: $4 \in ♥ \cap ♠ \cap ♣ \space$

Hence, Mr P would **not** know which set in specific he was looking at.

From there, I assume Mr Q was looking at the suit / set: $♥$.

This is because, this set has the greatest cardinality of elements found in other suits (3) *compared* to the cardinality of its elements that are not (0), so he could suggest that he knew Mr P wouldn't know what suit he was looking at, but here, Mr Q still would not know the denomination.

Is this correct? Was my reasoning rigorous enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly expanded version of the answer: let's walk through the logic line by line.

1) Mr. P says 'I don't know what this card is'. Since Mr. P knows the card's face value, we know that the card's face value can't be 'unique'; this eliminates things like the 2♠ from consideration because as soon as he sees '2' he knows the entire card. The remaining possible ranks of the card are A, 4, 5, and Q, as these are the ranks that appear more than once.

2) Mr. Q says "I knew you didn't know".  Since Mr. P and Mr. Q are (presumably perfect) logicians they're able to work the same logical deduction that appears in part 1). Mr. Q's statement then implies that all of the cards in the suit he was told are within that set; for instance, if the suit he was given was ♣ then he wouldn't have been able to make the statement he did, because if the card had been e.g. the 6♣ then Mr. P would have been able to deduce the card just from its face value. Since both spades and clubs have cards that are 'unique', we know the suit of the card is either diamonds or hearts.

3) Mr. P says "In that case, I know what it is." Again, as Messrs. P and Q are assumed to be perfect logicians, they can make the same deductions that were made in section 2; in particular, they both know that the card is either a heart or a diamond, and that it's one of A45Q.  But it's impossible for the face value to be the A, because in that case P wouldn't know whether it was a heart or a diamond; therefore, the card must be either the 4♥, the Q♥, or the 5♦.

4) Mr. Q says "Now I also know what it is." If the suit Mr. Q was told was hearts, then — after running the same deduction as we just did in part 3 — he still wouldn't be able to figure out if it was the 4♥ or the Q♥.  But since he's told us that he was able to determine the answer, then we know that the suit was diamonds and the card is the 5♦.

Answer (score 2):

(1) If Mr. P was told the denomination was 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, or K, he would immediately know the suit as well (2 of spades, 3 of spades, 6 of clubs, etc). Since he doesn't know the suit, the denomination he was told must have been A, 4, 5 or Q.

(2) If the suit was spades or clubs, there is a possibility that the denomination Mr. P was told was 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, or K, and then he would know what the card was. Since Mr. Q knows that Mr. P does not know what the card is, the suit must be hearts or diamonds.

(3) If the denomination was A, it could be A of hearts or A of diamonds, so Mr. P would still not know what the card was. But at this point Mr. P already knows what the card is. Therefore the denomination must be 4, 5, or Q.

(4) If the suit was hearts, the card might be 4 of hearts or Q of hearts, so Mr. Q would still not know what the card was. But Mr. Q already knows what the card is. Therefore the suit must be diamonds.

Hence the card is $\fbox{5 of diamonds}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the $5$ of diamonds.

P knows it's a $5$, so from his point of view (initially) it could be either the $5$ of clubs or the $5$ of diamonds.

However, Q says "I knew you didn't know what it was."  The chosen card can't be a club (or a spade), because there are several clubs (and spades) whose denominations would have immediately given away the answer to P.

But now P does know that it's the $5$ of diamonds.  Q can infer from this that it wasn't the Ace of diamonds, since (if P had been told it was an Ace) P wouldn't be able to tell from the information so far that it was the Ace of diamonds (and not the Ace of hearts).

Essentially, Q's statement eliminates all spades and clubs from consideration.  The fact that $4$ appears in the most suits isn't quite the information we need.

If the chosen card had been the $4$ of hearts, then Q would not be able to make his final statement: at that point, from Q's perspective, the Queen of hearts would still be a possibility.